# I installed "Local" on Windows10 and then uninstalled it.... why are there still so many instances of "fictional-university" running?

Tags: webserver, local, netstat

For one of the Udemy courses I installed Local as a local web development platform to play around with JS, PHP and WordPress.  Seems to work fine.  Yet, I uninstalled it (Local) for cleaning.
The weird thing is when I run netstat there are a dozen instances of "fictional-university" still running, connected to localhost.  I searched the entire computer for nginx and removed what I could.  I uninstalled Brackets, IIS.    I flushed the dns.  and still I get this...  any ideas?? This is happening on both of my computers!  any help or insights would be appreciated.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well that turned into another rabbit hole.

netstat -a showed the above image.  ^^^

netstat -aon | findstr 49714  got me a PID.

By using TaskManager/Details I was able to find out what processes were using those ports.

Both NVidiawebhelper and Viber were using that same hostname presumably after I installed Local.   So after going through all the startup programs and doing a dnsflush. "fictional-university" no longer shows up in netstat.... hooray??  This has me thinking that I would rather use OBSD or Linux in a virtual box.  Sorry for the newbie type questions.  Hope someone finds value in my tribulations.  :)